# DBFlow equivalent to SQL CONTAINS

Tags: android, sqlite, dbflow

How to execute a query with CONTAINS in DBFlow without writing a raw query?

I tried

```
public void searchTerm(String term) {
    SQLite().select()
    .from(MyModel.class)
    .where(MyModel_table.name.like(term))
    .or(MyModel_table.surname.like(term))
    .query();
}
```

But, no results are returned.

```
dbflow_version = "3.1.1"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this instead:

```
public void searchTerm(String term) {
    SQLite().select()
    .from(MyModel.class)
    .where(MyModel_table.name.like("%" + term + "%"))
    .or(MyModel_table.surname.like("%" + term + "%"))
    .query();
}
```